# Convert big string to decimal in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello i have big string value which is md5 of something now i need to convert it into the decimal value

for example

```
Dim md5_s As String = "6F05AF42533432A5513610FE839ACC86"
```

now i need output same like the online converters to this

> "54 70 48 53 65 70 52 50 53 51 51 52 51 50 65 53 53 49 51 54 49 48 70
>   69 56 51 57 65 67 67 56 54 "

is it possible i don't want spaces in the above converted decimal ?

vb.net help please

Okay here i tried and got it n is my approach works fine will this fine n work always right

```
 Dim t As String
        Dim a As String = "6F05AF42533432A5513610FE839ACC86"
        For Each c As Char In a
            t &= Convert.ToInt32(c)
        Next

        TextBox1.Text = t
```

will this one is right ?

result is same what i am looking for as

> 5470485365705250535151525150655353495154494870695651576567675654

so i assume this is right huh ?

Comment: Converting it into what decimal value? It is not clear what you want (even if it makes any sense). Rather than relying on abstract ideas, you should put a clear enough example (or a link to a web delivering what you want or something like this); but remember that you are expected to make some effort by your own. In any case, if this string is the result of an encryption process, there is nothing you can do with it other than trying to break the encryption (if possible at all).

Comment: okay i got it myself read main post

Comment: Ok so what you have got there is the decimal index of the ASCII values of each character in your string. user1244302's first code should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, your version works too (although I recommend using `AscW()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`).

Comment: hello vincent yes asc also works fine is Asc better than int32 how ?

Comment: Sorry, meant to write `AscW()`. I don't know exactly which is the better function (they do pretty much the same), but I recommend `AscW()` as you can be certain of what it does since it's only purpose is to get an Integer representation of a char.

Comment: What you are doing has no relationship with MD5. You are plainly converting numbers into characters (the characters follow certain order and you can convert each of them into its defining position; for example: A is 60 or whatever, B 61, etc.) and vice versa. Additionally this is not decimal, but integer. If you want to play around with conversions back and forth there are many alternatives (you might want to take a look at binary operations). But all this nothing to do with MD5 (or any other encryption algorithm).

Comment: thanks visual vincent will use AscW from now .also varocarbes nice explanation i used md5 just to make it clear that string is big

Comment: Doesn't matter how big the string is. It can be as big as your memory can hold. The function will work either way, but might take time for longer strings. One ASCII char takes 8 bits (1 byte) of memory. So for a string that would go out of memory it would need to have about 2 billion (2147483648 to be exact) characters in it.

Comment: If you are generating the hash you could output it to the desired format to begin with

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure this is what you are really looking for but this is what you asked for

```
  For count = 0 To md5_s.Length - 1
        Dim tempChar As String = md5_s.Substring(count, 1)
        Console.Write(Asc(tempChar))
    Next
```

What is more likely what you want is something like this

```
 Private Function HexToByteArray(ByVal hex As [String]) As Byte()
    Dim NumberChars As Integer = hex.Length
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(NumberChars / 2 - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To NumberChars - 1 Step 2
        bytes(i / 2) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return bytes
End Function
```

either way ... hope this helps

Comment: your code result answer as 54 only see my answer will it work for all md5 hash ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean "your code result answer as 54" the top code block I submitted displays            5470485365705250535151525150655353495154494870695651576567675654 but either way is fine

Comment: ur also works fine till its console when i output it to textbox TextBox1.Text = Asc(tempChar) it shows only 64

Comment: right ... you need something like textbox1.appendtext(asc(tempchar)) if you want it to be displayed in a textbox (or textbox1.text = textbox1.text & asc(tempchar) )

Comment: Your codes does the same thing using slightly different techniques. And yes, they can be used with all kinds of strings, or else Asc/AscW/Convert.ToInt32 wouldn't do their job.

Comment: @user1244302 : An even shorter version is `TextBox1.Text &= Asc(tempchar)`. :)

Comment: yes thats what i was going to write this operator results &= nice bro visual :)